# MA coefficients are not invertible (Python)

Tags: python, statsmodels

I am trying to fit an ARIMA model for time series forecasting. Below is the core code:

```
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA
history2 = [x for x in train]
pred2 = list()
for i in range(len(test)):
    model = ARIMA(history2, **order=(0,0,3)**)
    model_fit = model.fit(disp=-1)
    yhat = model_fit.forecast()[0]
    pred2.append(yhat)
    history2.append(test[i])
    print('>Predicted=%.4f, Expected=%.4f' % (yhat, test[i]))
```

In the above code, the model order(p, d, q) was set as (0,0,3), and the following error showed up. Based on my experiment, as long as I set the model order q>2, the same error would appear, while q=1 can work without any errors. Can anyone give me some hint on this issue ? For now, I don't fully understand the meaning and root cause of the error. Thanks !

ValueError: The computed initial MA coefficients are not invertible You should induce invertibility, choose a different model order, or you can pass your own start_params.

Comment: Possible duplicate? [non Invertible of a ARIMA model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30901460/non-invertible-of-a-arima-model)